# How to assign values and transfer to Long-format data

Tags: r

My data frame is like this. Each username is linked with 1 to many observations.

```
structure(list(username = structure(c(67L, 95L, 58L, 61L, 65L, 
66L, 10L, 2L, 41L, 85L, 29L, 76L, 59L, 77L, 97L, 22L, 96L, 47L, 
74L, 13L, 48L, 78L, 15L, 18L, 71L, 9L, 89L, 50L, 98L, 24L, 14L, 
90L, 64L, 1L, 93L, 62L, 52L, 83L, 88L, 82L, 73L, 8L, 45L, 6L, 
28L, 57L, 7L, 94L, 69L, 20L, 11L, 26L, 42L, 16L, 43L, 4L, 92L, 
70L, 5L, 56L), .Label = c("__aubssss", "_CurlyFryGuy_", "_JLovee", 
"100ProofWoman", "amoodyknapp", "ankushthebest10", "anna_michaux", 
"AnnetteVitelli3", "Bierkast", "Bigfamlife", "bluemoon357", "boogy1228", 
"Brenderzzz_", "brendochendo", "cappir", "CarmelScotsNews", "charlesdlcruz", 
"ChildOUniverse", "CllrKenPollock", "CoastCyclist", "Crampedsultana", 
"Crescen04324237", "CuddiCAPALOT", "d1no_nugget", "damnnndor", 
"danieldurrans", "dbrown13", "ducksandchucks", "EclecticCoding", 
"Felstedboy", "gengen0309", "Herbie555", "Ho8Go8L1N", "Honeylotus333", 
"huegolden", "iamesrvan", "IanSmalley3", "Ipeethree3", "Its_Jack_Brooo", 
"ItsBittie", "Jackie_montes", "james_southcott", "JanJoostBouwman", 
"Just_Jones33", "Karabo_Mtaung", "KathrynwithaY", "Keioney_kisses", 
"kikilovescats", "KLobstar", "LattaZakyra", "lilac_bun", "lizziemonkhouse", 
"m_melodias", "MainMandarin", "marge_cord", "Maverick1914", "May_leita", 
"mcbadlon", "MiyaDior", "msmrocks", "NaazhimSupreme", "napitupulu_a", 
"natashametzler", "Nick_Miles_", "nivanacampos", "nrazaliyah", 
"Ohh_Ziggy", "OnlySimphiwe", "orodelancs", "parrothead34", "PeachiesPromo", 
"PickledGingerBC", "popkis", "preciousrubie", "reverend_thom", 
"RevTinTin", "RudyJb1024", "samanthacraig15", "SandraRPearce1", 
"siempreAM0nae", "simplyaracelii", "SimStrength", "smutwiizard", 
"spaceboosh", "SplendentSweven", "stankloaf", "TaterSaladJD", 
"tayzer6", "terri2kool", "thehulkster", "ThisOffendsMeTV", "undersiegexo", 
"Warrior_Maiden", "WayCatPub", "WEAVYwonder_", "wsrphoto", "xkimmygirlx", 
"Yildiiiiiiiiz"), class = "factor"), positive = c(0.165, 0, 0.34, 
0.06, 0.106, 0, 0.292, 0, 0, 0.059, 0.139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.031, 
0, 0.119, 0, 0.457, 0.192, 0, 0, 0.128, 0.121, 0.101, 0.317, 
0, 0.528, 0.374, 0, 0.06, 0, 0.233, 0.092, 0.079, 0, 0, 0.174, 
0.094, 0.059, 0, 0.093, 0.103, 0.099, 0.097, 0.102, 0, 0.112, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.225, 0.095, 0.213, 0.116, 0.043, 0.078), compound = c(-0.1027, 
-0.3612, 0.5574, -0.886, 0.4738, 0, 0.9277, 0, -0.6077, 0.5023, 
0.5635, 0, 0, -0.4767, -0.8248, -0.4678, -0.296, 0.0094, 0, 0.9274, 
0.6124, -0.6664, 0, 0.6486, 0.6116, 0.5399, 0.8926, 0, 0.6792, 
0.9768, 0, 0.2732, -0.7073, 0.892, -0.7783, 0.3818, 0, -0.6739, 
0.7314, 0.4588, -0.2411, 0, -0.2212, 0.2023, -0.2244, 0.296, 
-0.4417, -0.7003, 0.2946, -0.6808, 0, 0, -0.0387, -0.3816, 0.5106, 
0.296, 0.6739, 0.5487, -0.2023, 0.5229), Date = structure(c(38L, 
38L, 35L, 35L, 30L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 19L, 
19L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 7L, 24L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 39L, 38L, 30L, 
29L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 21L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 34L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 
39L, 39L, 36L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 
5L, 1L, 24L, 39L, 31L, 31L, 28L), .Label = c("2020-02-02", "2020-02-07", 
"2020-02-08", "2020-02-09", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", 
"2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-21", 
"2020-02-22", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-29", 
"2020-03-01", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-13", 
"2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", 
"2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", 
"2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-29", 
"2020-03-30", "2020-03-31"), class = "factor"), agegroup = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("MA", 
"OA", "YA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

I hope to generate an output table with a new variable time (added):

If time is between

```
May 1st 2019 to Mar 31st 2020, code 1 
April 1st 2020 to June 30th 2020, code 2
July 1st 2020 to Dec 31th 2020, code 3
Jan 1st 2020 to April 30th 2021, code 4
```

The desired output is like this. If a user has multiple observations in the specific time range, calculate the mean **compound** value. If a user does not have observation in the specific time range, code N.A.

```
username  agegroup  mean(compound) time
a           YA          0.2         1
a           YA          0.3         2
a           YA          na          3
a           YA          na          4
```

I tried, but it does not work

```
twitter_wide <- data %>% mutate(
     Condition = ifelse(Date >= "2019-05-1" & Date <= "2020-03-31", "T1", 
                         ifelse(Date >= "2020-04-01" & Date <= "2020-06-30", "T2", 
                         ifelse(Date >= "2020-07-1" & Date <= "2020-12-31", "T3", 
                         ifelse(Date >= "2021-01-01" & Date <= "2021-04-30", "T4", NA)))
                         + ) %>% 
        group_by(username, agegroup) %>% 
        summarise(compound = mean(`compound`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
       pivot_wider(names_from = Condition, names_prefix = "", values_from = compound)
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
cts <- as.Date(c("2019-05-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-07-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-04-30"))

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         condition = cut(Date, cts, paste('code', 1:4),  include.lowest = TRUE))
     
          username positive compound       Date agegroup condition
1        Ohh_Ziggy    0.165  -0.1027 2020-03-30       YA    code 1
2     WEAVYwonder_    0.000  -0.3612 2020-03-30       YA    code 1
3         mcbadlon    0.340   0.5574 2020-03-26       YA    code 1
4   NaazhimSupreme    0.060  -0.8860 2020-03-26       YA    code 1
5     nivanacampos    0.106   0.4738 2020-03-21       YA    code 1
6       nrazaliyah    0.000   0.0000 2020-03-20       YA    code 1
7       Bigfamlife    0.292   0.9277 2020-03-18       YA    code 1
8    _CurlyFryGuy_    0.000   0.0000 2020-03-18       MA    code 1
9    Jackie_montes    0.000  -0.6077 2020-03-18       YA    code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

twitter <- structure(list(username = structure(c(67L, 95L, 58L, 61L, 65L, 
                                      66L, 10L, 2L, 41L, 85L, 29L, 76L, 59L, 77L, 97L, 22L, 96L, 47L, 
                                      74L, 13L, 48L, 78L, 15L, 18L, 71L, 9L, 89L, 50L, 98L, 24L, 14L, 
                                      90L, 64L, 1L, 93L, 62L, 52L, 83L, 88L, 82L, 73L, 8L, 45L, 6L, 
                                      28L, 57L, 7L, 94L, 69L, 20L, 11L, 26L, 42L, 16L, 43L, 4L, 92L, 
                                      70L, 5L, 56L), .Label = c("__aubssss", "_CurlyFryGuy_", "_JLovee", 
                                                                "100ProofWoman", "amoodyknapp", "ankushthebest10", "anna_michaux", 
                                                                "AnnetteVitelli3", "Bierkast", "Bigfamlife", "bluemoon357", "boogy1228", 
                                                                "Brenderzzz_", "brendochendo", "cappir", "CarmelScotsNews", "charlesdlcruz", 
                                                                "ChildOUniverse", "CllrKenPollock", "CoastCyclist", "Crampedsultana", 
                                                                "Crescen04324237", "CuddiCAPALOT", "d1no_nugget", "damnnndor", 
                                                                "danieldurrans", "dbrown13", "ducksandchucks", "EclecticCoding", 
                                                                "Felstedboy", "gengen0309", "Herbie555", "Ho8Go8L1N", "Honeylotus333", 
                                                                "huegolden", "iamesrvan", "IanSmalley3", "Ipeethree3", "Its_Jack_Brooo", 
                                                                "ItsBittie", "Jackie_montes", "james_southcott", "JanJoostBouwman", 
                                                                "Just_Jones33", "Karabo_Mtaung", "KathrynwithaY", "Keioney_kisses", 
                                                                "kikilovescats", "KLobstar", "LattaZakyra", "lilac_bun", "lizziemonkhouse", 
                                                                "m_melodias", "MainMandarin", "marge_cord", "Maverick1914", "May_leita", 
                                                                "mcbadlon", "MiyaDior", "msmrocks", "NaazhimSupreme", "napitupulu_a", 
                                                                "natashametzler", "Nick_Miles_", "nivanacampos", "nrazaliyah", 
                                                                "Ohh_Ziggy", "OnlySimphiwe", "orodelancs", "parrothead34", "PeachiesPromo", 
                                                                "PickledGingerBC", "popkis", "preciousrubie", "reverend_thom", 
                                                                "RevTinTin", "RudyJb1024", "samanthacraig15", "SandraRPearce1", 
                                                                "siempreAM0nae", "simplyaracelii", "SimStrength", "smutwiizard", 
                                                                "spaceboosh", "SplendentSweven", "stankloaf", "TaterSaladJD", 
                                                                "tayzer6", "terri2kool", "thehulkster", "ThisOffendsMeTV", "undersiegexo", 
                                                                "Warrior_Maiden", "WayCatPub", "WEAVYwonder_", "wsrphoto", "xkimmygirlx", 
                                                                "Yildiiiiiiiiz"), class = "factor"), positive = c(0.165, 0, 0.34, 
                                                                                                                  0.06, 0.106, 0, 0.292, 0, 0, 0.059, 0.139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.031, 
                                                                                                                  0, 0.119, 0, 0.457, 0.192, 0, 0, 0.128, 0.121, 0.101, 0.317, 
                                                                                                                  0, 0.528, 0.374, 0, 0.06, 0, 0.233, 0.092, 0.079, 0, 0, 0.174, 
                                                                                                                  0.094, 0.059, 0, 0.093, 0.103, 0.099, 0.097, 0.102, 0, 0.112, 
                                                                                                                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.225, 0.095, 0.213, 0.116, 0.043, 0.078), compound = c(-0.1027, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.3612, 0.5574, -0.886, 0.4738, 0, 0.9277, 0, -0.6077, 0.5023, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         0.5635, 0, 0, -0.4767, -0.8248, -0.4678, -0.296, 0.0094, 0, 0.9274, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         0.6124, -0.6664, 0, 0.6486, 0.6116, 0.5399, 0.8926, 0, 0.6792, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         0.9768, 0, 0.2732, -0.7073, 0.892, -0.7783, 0.3818, 0, -0.6739, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         0.7314, 0.4588, -0.2411, 0, -0.2212, 0.2023, -0.2244, 0.296, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.4417, -0.7003, 0.2946, -0.6808, 0, 0, -0.0387, -0.3816, 0.5106, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         0.296, 0.6739, 0.5487, -0.2023, 0.5229), Date = structure(c(38L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     38L, 35L, 35L, 30L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     19L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 7L, 24L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 39L, 38L, 30L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     29L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 21L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 34L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     39L, 39L, 36L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 1L, 24L, 39L, 31L, 31L, 28L), .Label = c("2020-02-02", "2020-02-07", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-02-08", "2020-02-09", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-21", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-02-22", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-29", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-03-01", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-13", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-29", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2020-03-30", "2020-03-31"), class = "factor"), agegroup = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("MA", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "OA", "YA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- twitter %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  mutate(time = case_when(Date %within%
                     interval(ymd("2019-05-01"),
                              ymd("2020-03-31")) ~ "code 1",
                   Date %within%
                     interval(ymd("2020-04-01"),
                              ymd("2020-06-30")) ~ "code 2",
                   Date %within%
                     interval(ymd("2020-07-01"),
                              ymd("2020-12-31")) ~ "code 3",
                   Date %within%
                     interval(ymd("2021-01-01"),
                              ymd("2021-04-30")) ~ "code 4")) %>%
  mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("code 1", "code 2",
                                        "code 3", "code 4"))) %>%
  group_by(username, agegroup, time, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise("mean(compound)" = mean(compound, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: It shows the follwoing error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `time`.
ℹ `time = case_when(...)`.
x could not find function "%within%"

Comment: You need to load the lubridate package first (like I did at the top of my answer)